# How to make a dictionary of two sets of related objects in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In making a simple forum, I want to make a dictionary of topics along with their authors (Users who are OPs) to be sent to template containing list of topics.

Here is the model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def num_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.count()

    def num_replies(self):
        return max(0, self.post_set.count() - 1)

    def last_post(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by("created")[0]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.creator) + " - " + self.title
```

I'm not sure how (and where) to create the dictionary. I tried making the dict in views like this:

```
def forum(request, forum_id):
    args = {}
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(forum=forum_id).order_by("-created")
    ops = {}
    for t in topics:
        ops[t] = User.objects.get(id = t.creator)
...
```

However this yields to this error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

I am beginner to django and got stock here so appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.creator` is already the `User` object so you can assign it as:

```
ops[t] = t.creator
```

And pythonic way of building dicts is the passing list of two-item tuples to the dict constructor:

```
ops = dict((t.title, t.creator) for t in topics)
```

But anyway you don't need the dict of strings to iterate in the template.  Pass the queryset as is:

```
def forum(request, forum_id):
    topics = Topic.objects.select_related('creator') \
                          .filter(forum=forum_id).order_by("-created")    
    return render(request, 'forum.html', {'topics': topics})
```

And the in the `forum.html`:

```
<ul>
{% for topic in topics %}
    <li>{{ topic.title }} by {{ topic.creator }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```